# Is there a R implementation of isolation forest for anomaly detection?

Tags: machine-learning, r, scikit-learn, random-forest

Is there a R implementation of isolation forest for anomaly detection?

Similar to the implementation from [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html).

Answer (score 10):

See the `iforest` package on [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iforest/) or on [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/iforest/):

This package implements an anomaly detection method that detects data-anomalies using binary trees. Using the property that anomalies are more susceptible to isolation, anomalies can be detected as data points which have short expected path lengths.

> Isolation Forest detects data-anomalies using binary trees. Platform:
>   R Reference: Fei Tony Liu, Kai Ming Ting, and Zhi-Hua Zhou, “Isolation
>   Forest”, IEEE International Conference on Data Mining 2008 (ICDM 08)

or the [`isofor` package on GitHub](https://github.com/Zelazny7/isofor):

One efficient way of performing outlier detection in high-dimensional datasets is to use random forests. The isofor ‘isolates’ observations by randomly selecting a feature and then randomly selecting a split
value between the maximum and minimum values of the selected feature.

Comment: Interesting! since both packages are not in CRAN, is there an easy "for dummies" way to install them, at least on a Linux (not OSX) VM ?

Comment: install `devtools` (`install.packages("devtools")`) and then `devtools::install_github("Zelazny7/isofor")`

Answer (score 5):

**Solitude** ([CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/package=solitude) / [github](https://github.com/talegari/solitude)): Isolation forest is anomaly detection method introduced by the paper Isolation based Anomaly Detection (Liu, Ting and Zhou )

PS: I am the author of this package

Comment: I think you forgot to export most methods, only isolation_forest is visible

Comment: @Cos predict method exists. This vignette should help. https://bit.ly/2Qwbs8L

Comment: Hi, I just discovered your package when looking up isoforest in R. Thanks for the easy to use implementation. I had a couple of questions for you: Is there a way to access individual trees information? I guess its kept private (the ranger fit)? Also, I see you have set y to a jumbled number (based on number of rows in the data frame)...could you please explain the reasoning for this as it wasnt clear for me. Shouldnt the isoforest run unsupervised? Thanks!